# When do nested child elements expand their parent elment?

Tags: css

In many places I have put elmeents nested in other elements.  I can't deduce when a child element causes the parent element to expand.  I don't have any code to post as this is a general conceptual question so that I can design as needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing that you should understand is the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html). That will help you understand how properties of an element cause it to have the size and dimensions that it has. Another good resource is [here](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/).

To answer your main question in the most simple manner (and being very general):

- Block level elements take up as much width as possible (obeying their CSS width rule). Their height is dependent on their content and the CSS height property.

  - Elements like `div`, `p`, and `ul` are all block.
  - These will generally cause your parent element to expand.
- Inline level elements will continue to flow together in a line, filling up only as much width and height as necessary.

  - Elements like `span`, `em`, `strong` are all inline.
  - These will cause your parent element to expand only when there are enough of them on the same line to warrant another line.

There are many ways to tweak the display of elements with CSS.

Comment: The box model doesn't really cover how descendant elements affect their container or ancestor. It's very important for fundamental understanding, though. More in-depth information can be found in the [visual formatting model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html) (with [details](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html)).

Comment: One thing to note if you have some dynamic <p> elements and you float them so that they will flow left to right instead of up to down (like you said they are block level and take up the entire line) they will not expand the parent div....also to note...if you remove the float and make their display inline...they will flow left to right and cause the parent dive to expand.... problem part way solved...thank you...now the next issue.

Comment: next issue is I have these php generated tags that expand over time..they now flow left to right in a containing div called tag_hold.....tag_hold has a property maximum-width..which worked before...now it does not work...the expanding <p>'s just continue off to the right infinitely...

Answer (score 2):

Get firebug for firefox. You can browse the DOM (the HTML structure of the page) and it will highlight elements according to how the "browser's eye" sees them (versus how they look aesthetically).

A few general rules of thumb:

- Children will expand their parent's height as long as they're not floated or absolutely positioned, but...
- You can "clear" a series of floated images http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html to make the parent element expand
- If you use top positioning for a relatively positioned child element, the browser will still see that element in the exact same place. In other words the height of the parent element will stay the same regardless of where the child is relatively positioned to.
- Using positive or negative margins on a child that is display: block will add or subtract height from its parent